# MySQL DB normalization

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, sqlite, core-data

I've got a single table DB with 100K rows.  There are about 30 columns and 28 of them are varchars / tiny text and one of them is an int primary key and one of them is a blob.

My question, is in terms of performance, would it be better to separate the blob from the rest of the table and store them in their own table with foreign key constraint to the primary id?

The table will eventually be turned into a sqlite persistent store for iOS core data and a lot of the searching / filtering will be done based on the NSPredicate for the lighter varchar columns.

Sorry if this is too subjective, but I'm thinking there is a recommended way.

Thanks!

Comment: Database normalization has nothing to do with datatypes.  If there is only 1 blob item per row, the table it's in is probably the best spot for it.

Comment: if you have huge blob-data, it's most likely the best way to store it in files and have the path to it inside the database isntead.

Comment: Why is this tagged with mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This totally depends on data usage.

If you need the data everytime you query the table, there is no difference in haviong a separate table for it (as long as blob data is unique in each row - that is, "as long as the database is normalized").

If you don'T need the blob data but only metadata from other columns, there may be a speed bonus qhen querying if the blob has its own table. querying the blob data is slower thoguh, as you need to query bowth tables.

The USUAL way is not to store any blob data inside the database (at least not huge data), but store the binary data into files and have the fiel path inside the database instead. This is recommended, as binary data most likely doesn'T benefit from being inside a DBMS (not indexable, sortable, groupable, ..), so there is no drawback of storing it inside files, while the database isn't optimized for binary data ('cause, again, it can't do much with it anyway).

Comment: I disagree with that "USUAL" way.  Although it works for local applications, having to deal with maintaining separate security and access rights to a file system along with a database generally makes that option less attractive when developing a server-based system.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That really depends. Web-based applications, where only you and maybe some trusted developers got access to the server, setting up appropriate access right's shouldn't be too much of a deal.

Comment: Ya, the blob data is not binary, its text blobs.  Most likely overkill, but when I was capturing the data, I didn't know what to expect.  It would be nice to be searchable and eventually might want to think about using solr to index it, but now, its about 5kb of text per blob.  Storing it in individual files would be too much for me, as I wouldn't want the file overhead or management issues with iOS.

Comment: @4m1r If you wnat it to be searcheable, use `text`instead of `blob`.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  Super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `SELECT * FROM table` (which you shouldn't if you don't need the BLOB field actually) then yes, the query will be faster because in that case pages with BLOB won't be touched.

If you do frequent `SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM table` (all fields are non-BLOBs) then yes, storing  BLOBS in a separate table will make the query faster because of the same reason - MySQL will have to read less pages.

If however the BLOB is selected frequently then it makes no sense to keep it separately.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  The blobs are only needed when the user requests the blob data from the Master -> Detail view.  So very infrequently.

Comment: Then you should actually split it.

Comment: One more moment I forgot to mention.
If a record is less than 7kB than the BLOB will be stored in the index page. If longer - only first 768 bytes (20 if Barracuda format) are stored in the index page - the rest goes to external pages.

So if your BLOB are longer than 7kB then it probably makes no sense to split the table too. With Barracuda - for sure. With Antelope - depending on how big 768 bytes is comparing to other fields in a record.

Answer (score 0):

Blobs are stored on disk only the point to the storage is in memory in Mysql.  Moving it to another table with a foreign key will not noticeably  help your performance.  Don't know if this is the case for sqlite.